# How to create Http Connection using AsyncTask class?

Tags: android

I am trying to create HTTP connection using AsyncTask class.

Is it possible to create HTTP connection ?

Can you suggest sample source code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As an inner class inside your activity :

```
public final class HttpTask
        extends
        AsyncTask<String/* Param */, Boolean /* Progress */, String /* Result */> {

    private HttpClient mHc = new DefaultHttpClient();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        publishProgress(true);
        // Do the usual httpclient thing to get the result
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... progress) {
        // line below coupled with 
        //    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS) 
        //    before setContentView 
        // will show the wait animation on the top-right corner
        MyActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        publishProgress(false);
        // Do something with result in your activity
    }

}
```

Then somewhere in your activity :

```
new HttpTask().execute(someParams...);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this may help u...

http://androidbeginner.blogspot.com/2010/01/communication-with-httprequest.html

Atul yadav