# How to use HttpClient (or other HTTP class) to retrieve JSON asynchronously

Tags: android, json, http, asynchronous

I've got the content from a HttpClient, but I'm not sure where to go next, in order to parse my JSON result. Also, how do I do this asynchronously so that I can display a wait dialog to the user with the option of cancelling the current request (not bothered about the UI example, how do I setup the HTTP class to be cancellable)?

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://mysite/test.json");
    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    // What if I want to cancel now??
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
    }
```

Comment: use a thread. What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android has a class specifically for this sort of thing: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

See the answer to this question: [How to create Http Connection using AsyncTask class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205128/how-to-create-http-connection-using-asynctask-class)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Android programmer but I imagine you need to start a thread.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/