# how to avoid application not responding while net is disconnected in android

Tags: android

i create login page . this login page validate from server database .if net is available mean if click login button means it works fine . if i disable net then click login button means it shows error the application was not responding .. how to avoid this error using my code

```
      i try this code
          login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            name = username.getText().toString();
            pass = password.getText().toString();
            String Str_check2 = app_preferences.getString("checked", "no");
            if(Str_check2.equals("yes"))
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("username", name);
                editor.putString("password", pass);
                 editor.commit();
            }
            if(name.equals("") || pass.equals(""))
            {
                 Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Please Enter Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else

            try {
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost("url/login.php");
                // Add your data
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserEmail", name.trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", pass.trim()));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                data = new byte[256];

                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int len = 0;
                while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
                {
                    buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
                }

                inputStream.close();
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                 System.out.println(e);

                 //alertDialog.cancel();

            }
            if(buffer.charAt(0)=='Y')
            {

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),another.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                 System.out.println("Invalid username and password")
            }         

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you should not do your network task in main thread, which seems like u are doing in OnClick.

To avoid connection hangs, you need to set connection timeout. for easy use of http operations i have put together a http library in github, you can either use this code for your sample reference or use it as a library

https://github.com/nareshsvs/android-libraries

Answer (score 0):

add a null check here..

```
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    if(response != null){
    inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                    data = new byte[256];
```

because when server connectivity fails `execute()` returns null and you need see and make sure its not null.. and just like Naresh said do  not do server communication in MainThtread.. see [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which will come handy..

Comment: where can i wrote this line if(response != null){

Comment: i use ur edit code but same error comes .. what can i do please tell me

Comment: threadid=3 reacting to the signal 3,wrote stack trace to /data/anr/traces.txt.. this only print log file

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Naresh do not use main thread for your every task. Use `Service` or `AsyncTask` to execute your long running Network Tasks.

Comment: Here is an Example ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205128/how-to-create-http-connection-using-asynctask-class