# Android - JSON Connection to Web Server / MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am in my first android programming days, and I am stuck at this.

I'm trying to establish a connection (log in page) with a MySQL database through PHP in an android project. I've been successful in the emulator with the host's ip address inside my network. However, I can't seem to connect to the external IP, which is fulcral because I mean to implement it on real devices.

On the device, since it's outside the network, I can't connect either way.

Result of unsuccessful connection is crash, and LogCat stays stuck at Button - Login.

I've added Internet Permissions to the Manifest.

The only change between a successful connection and an unsuccessful one is the adress (internal to external).

```
//JSON parser code:

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String

    return jObj;

}


//Creating the JSON

JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running your local server in the same WiFi network with real device, check IP of your PC server using **ipconfig** (Windows), it would be something like 192.168.100.101 or similar. So you just connect to this address from your device.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer.

However, I don't have a WiFi network setup. I have a virtual machine with an external IP activated (currently hosting web service), and I was hoping to connect any android device to it (MySQL) via PHP and Internet.

It should work as well as with the intranet IP in the emulator, right?

Comment: @SilentFreak Let me clarify - you have your PHP server running and visible from the web, right?

Comment: Yes, I have a server running on the web with a XAMPP/Apache/MySQL configuration. I also have network access to it, and the only way I could make this to work was through that intranet on the emulator. Simply by changing the IP to the web one, app crashes after pressing button to connect/query.

Comment: Ok, anyway - could you please update your question by adding LogCat logs related with crash?

Comment: Also, you say that server is visible from the web, but "On the device, since it's outside the network, I can't connect either way." What means outside the network? Server is not visible generally from the web, only from your local network? In this case you need to find ip of the server and hardcode it in android app

Comment: I notice I wasn't clear about that issue.I have a server always visible from web.Usually when developing I connect to it through a cable/local network,using the local IP.When I use that IP on the android code I can use the app. If I change for the web, app crashes. Device connects to internet.


LogCat:

03-19 16:37:50.683: D/Button(773): Login
03-19 16:38:13.623: I/dalvikvm(773): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-19 16:38:13.772: I/dalvikvm(773): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Error on emulator:
Sorry!
Activity Login Account (in aplication <AplicationName>) is not responding.

Comment: When I say I can use the app, that is on the emulator (when I'm connected to local network).

Comment: Can you please post logs related to connection errors? If you check internet connection state somewhere, you may need to add permission 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: I've added the mentioned permission and got no different result. The only logs on log cat are the ones I posted, app simply crashes (asks to "Force Close or Wait") and no more logs are registered. Is there any other place to check those logs (I'm also new to Eclipse)? Might this situation be related to a need for an assyncronous connection (I read somewhere that an internet connection shouldn't be made on a main activity, and assync would sort that out)?

Comment: " read somewhere that an internet connection shouldn't be made on a main activity, and assync would sort that out" - exactly. And more, Force close or wait means you're doing something heavy on UI thread.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205128/how-to-create-http-connection-using-asynctask-class check this :)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I learnt how to do it assincronously, and that did the trick.